# Hugo Template eq Operation Not Functioning as Expected

Tags: hugo-shortcode

I have a Hugo shortcode where I am checking the day of the week:

```
{{ $weekDay := now.Weekday }}
{{ if eq $weekDay "Monday" }}
    ...display content here...
{{ end }}
```

However, the `$weekDay` value, when it is `Monday` is not evaluating to `true` and the content within the `if` block is not being displayed.

When I do the following, the content is being displayed:

```
{{ $weekDay := now.Weekday }}
{{ if eq $weekDay now.Weekday }}
    ...display content here...
{{ end }}
```

The content in the `if` block is being displayed. Is the `$weekDay` variable not a string datatype?

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected, the operands being compared were of two separate datatypes. Using the `String` property results in a comparison of two String datatypes:

```golang
{{ $weekDay := now.Weekday }}
{{ if eq $weekDay.String "Monday" }}
...
{{ end }}
```